# Align the sidebar to the main content of page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a website,but the sidebar is not aligning to the main content of the website and is overlapping another div.
Link to the website http://www.inseeks.com/

[image: screen shot of how it should look]

Comment: place it outside the frame content

Comment: You want it to align next to main content section? You need to specify widths for main content and sidebar and float them.

Comment: can you plz add the screen shot like how exactly you need this alignment ??

Answer (score 2):

```
    .site-main .sidebar-inner {
        margin: 6px auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you making any other changes? Because this just floats it to the left

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your `.sidebar-inner` inside your `#content`

```
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
    <div class="sidebar-inner">
```

Then float it to the right.

```
.sidebar-inner {
    float: right;
    //add necessary paddings or margins.
}
```

Comment: But then the main content is disrupted

Comment: @turtle, Hi, please post your code in jsfiddle so that it's easier to modify.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the `position: absolute;` on `.site-main .sidebar-container`
- Change `width: 100%;` to `width: 300px;`
- Add `float: right;`

Add the following style to the css.

```
#primary 
{
    float: left;
}
```

That above should change so the sidebar will be on the left and no longer be overlapping the other content.